# mismatched input '$1' expecting LEFT_PAREN

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to pig Latin scripting I don't know whether am i doing is right or wrong please help me.
Below is  the sample which I have the first group by player name that is first parameter now data which is present in bag i want to order them by score desc
Is it possible to get it done in pig by single statement?

(B.Kumarr,{(B.Kumarr,18),(B.Kumarr,10),(B.Kumarr,38)})

```
cricData3 = FOREACH cricData2 GENERATE $0,ORDER $1.$1 By DESC;
```

(B.Kumarr,{(B.Kumarr,38),(B.Kumarr,18),(B.Kumarr,10)})